# Show value from input in exporting html code to pdf using jspdf

Tags: jquery, html, jspdf

If my post duplicated, please give me references.

because i failed finding post that appropriate from my problem.

I have simple form

```
<div class="form-control" id="input">
    <label>Name :</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off" required>
    <br><label>Class :</label>
    <select name="myclass" id="myclass" value="--">
        <option>--</option>
        <option>class 1</option>
        <option>class 2</option>
        <option>class 3</option>
    </select>
    <br><label>Date :</label>
    <input type="text" name="date" id="date" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>

<div>
    <button type="button" onclick="printInput()" >Submit Data</button>
</div>
```

So, here I have make simple code to generate my form to pdf :

```
<script src="dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function printInput()
    {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.fromHTML($("#input").get(0), 10, 10, {'width': 180});
        doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
    }
</script>
```

But, value from `input` and `select` not show.

how to make value from them showing in pdf ?

Answer (score 4):

Add div around date and Name

```
<div class="form-control" id="input">
    <label><div id="NameHide">Name :</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off" required>
    <br><label>Class :</label>
    <select name="myclass" id="myclass" value="--">
        <option>--</option>
        <option>class 1</option>
        <option>class 2</option>
        <option>class 3</option>
    </select>
    <br><label><div id="DateHide">Date :</label>
    <input type="text" name="date" id="date" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>

<div>
    <button type="button" onclick="printInput()" >Submit Data</button>
</div>
```

In script

```
<script src="dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function printInput()
    {
document.getElementById("NameHide").innerHTML="Name"+document.getElementById("name").value;
document.getElementById("DateHide").innerHTML="Date"+document.getElementById("date").value;
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.fromHTML($("#input").get(0), 10, 10, {'width': 180});
        doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
document.getElementById("NameHide").innerHTML="Name";
document.getElementById("DateHide").innerHTML="Date";
    }
</script>
```

JSpdf is not fully developed yet. So we need to write our own logic to print from user input.
This logic is appending value to html content. then renders html and again remove previous append.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code is not complete enough to judge, but I think you haven't get the select value properly! You've just selected the input tages.
with jQuery select the values like this:

```
name = $('input[name=name]').val();
class = $('select[name= myclass]').val();
date = $('select[name= date]').val();
```

alternatively in js :

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
```

Comment: how to set in jsPDF that variables ?